# How to add existing categories into a post using wp_insert_post

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I tried to add a category based on a post as seen on this link:
[How we add new categories by wp_insert_post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/93709/how-we-add-new-categories-by-wp-insert-post)

Here, I added 'post_category' and default category IDs in an array as shown below:

```
$my_post = array(
    'post_title'    => 'test',
    'post_content'  => 'hello',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_author'   =>  1,
    'post_type'     => 'product',
    'post_category' => array(2,3,4,5)
 );
 $post_id = wp_insert_post($my_post);
```

All of the fields above have been added, except for the post_category. I wanted to add more than one category per product, and what I am using is an array.

What is probably the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wp_set_object_terms()` to assign taxonomy terms to a post.

```
wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $terms, $taxonomy, true);
```

Where `$terms` - A single term slug, single term id, or array of either term slugs 
    or ids. Will replace all existing related terms in this taxonomy.

See documentation: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms

Edit:

In your case, it will look like:

```
wp_set_object_terms($post_id, array(2,3,4,5), 'category', true);
```

Please check for any syntax error.

Comment: what should I put in a $terms and $taxonomy so that I can insert category posts in an array?

Comment: Check the edit, use proper category ids.

Comment: I tried this but didn't work.. :(

Comment: Print and check what the function returns. Check documentation for return types.

Comment: print_r(wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $terms['category'], 'category')); but this returns to category values.., I tried the sku and it's working.. update_post_meta()

Comment: Yes, if it is successful it returns category ids which are tagged. Is it working if you use slugs instaed of ids?